# Create lookup column with multi select option using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, lookup-column, pnp-powershell

I want to create lookup column with multi select option using PNP PowerShell in SPO.

I am able to create lookup field below script. But i dont know what is the property to be added to make it multi select field.
Also, I need to select 2 more columns as additional fields. How to include it.

```
$SiteURL = "****"
$ListName= "Projects"
$DisplayName = "Parent Project"
$InternalName = "ParentProject"
 
$ParentListName="Parent Projects"
$LookupField = "Title" #Internal Name
 
#Connect to the site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive       
 
#Add Lookup Field to the List    
Add-PnPField -List $ListName -Type Lookup -DisplayName $DisplayName -InternalName $InternalName -AddToDefaultView
 
#Set Field Properties
Set-PnPField -List $ListName -Identity $InternalName -Values @{LookupList=(Get-PnPList $ParentListName).Id.ToString(); LookupField=$LookupField}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the field property *AllowMultipleValues* which you want to set to *$true*.

```
Set-PnPField -List $list -Identity $InternalName -Values @{LookupList=(Get-PnPList $ParentListName).Id.ToString(); LookupField=$LookupField; AllowMultipleValues=$true}
```

[FieldLookup.AllowMultipleValues property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee537717(v=office.15))

If you want to add additional columns related to the lookup-column, I think the only way is to do it using [Add-PnPFieldFromXml](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFieldFromXml.html).

[Create lookup field with additional columns](https://olafd.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/create-lookup-field-with-additional-columns/)